# Compare Huge XML Rows with Database Table Records - Custom Requirement

Tags: java, database, xml-parsing, compare, stax

### Problem

We have an XML like (its having some non unicode which needs to be filtered of) data,

```
<row><div>1234</div><dept>ABCD</dept></row>
<row><div>5678</div><dept>EFGH</dept></row>
```

*Just mentioning only 2 column tags for ease of understanding. Actually it has more than 20 column tags in each*

XML data is directly inserted as records into an Oracle schema table as,

```
div_c  qdept
1234   ABCD
5678   EFGH
```

### More information

1. XML file is more than 9 Gigs and available in FTP.
2. Database table column names might be different from XML column tag names.
3. Might have to add/define some Rules to filter out the rows.

### Question

What would be the appropriate way to parse this huge XML and find out whether that record exists in the database table? Any open source tools available to utilize?

### What Am Trying

- Wrote StAX parser using default implementation(XMLInputFactory) with Invalid characters fiter (FilterReader)
- Planning to split the XML as chunks
- Have concurrent threads processing each of the chunks
- Each thread will generate a query to check whether that exists in database or not (i know its absurd)
- Have a connection pool created and execute those queries by each of the thread

I know this is really worst what I am doing and it will take years to complete, I really need some advice on this like whether to go with any ORM to make the checking easy and make the XML parsing fast.

Some suggestions like that would really help me.

Comment: you can try the apache digester: http://commons.apache.org/digester/
You can write your own class and push it onto the digester stack. Then, based on the regex rules (which you specify), the digester will call different methods on this object with the tags and their values as parameters. In there you can map them to your database tables and even insert them to the database. The digester uses SAX so it should be able to handle this huge file, however you will probably need more  memory than usual

Comment: I am from a bit different world (.NET) and in my world I would do the following. I would use XmlReader (to avoid loading the document to memory) to read the file and write another file in a form that can be imported to the database. I would use a tool/command like bulkInsert in SqlServer to import the data to a temporary table/database. I would run a SQL query to compare both tables/databases. Also, how do you define if a record exists in the database? Do all columns have to match or just the key? What if a key matches but some columns not? I don't think ORM will be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. I think you were right to use StAX. You definitely want to stream and StAX seems to have the simplest API for streaming XML. I wouldn't go to ORM right away. Most ORM is to round-trip data. It saves you work for mechanical transformations. That makes it good when you have very structured data but the mapping between the two schemas is not very complicated. Here you are trying import data from one format into another. It sounds like your large dataset has a fairly simple schema but the mapping is the more complicated part. Go with custom code. Pawel's suggestion of the temporary table sounds good. Try to do as much processing as you can in stored procedures that operate on the whole dataset at once (old and imported). You don't want to keep transferring those rows back and forth from the database to your app.